# Chrome DevTools- Saving only CSS or JS results

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have Dev Tools for Chrome installed.  I know I can get the output in HAR format. However, I would only like to have CSS HAR, JS HAR file to analyse results.  Is it possible to do that?  When I save as HAR file on JS tab, it saves ALL types of data in that file.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in DevTools. It shouldn't be too hard to write something that takes the HAR file that DevTools outputs, and filters it so that only the CSS and JS information remains.

Judging by this archived feature request, it doesn't look like the team plans on implementing this feature: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=620607